# Can't get bluetooth headphone mic working with pi

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, pi-3b+, microphone

I am trying to get my Bluetooth headphone mic working with pi b+, my headphone gets connected and audio output is also working but its mic isn't working with pi. I had gone through several online forums but didn't find any working solution, but there must be a way to get the mics of Bluetooth headphones also working. And seems like this issue is probably with every one who is trying to use Bluetooth headphone's audio in as well as out both working.
my specifications:

- headphone:"boat rockerz 510"
- headphone profile: A2DP
- pi board: version b+
- os: raspbian official